# Wonder Woman Hair Vs Angel Wings

Tags: minifigures

Will [this wonder woman hairpiece](https://store.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98725pb03#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) work with [a transparent neck bracket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18986#T=S&C=12&O=%7B%22color%22:12,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) , some clip plates, and white [feathered wings](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11100&idColor=1&name=White%20Minifigure,%20Wing%20Feathered&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Wear%5D#T=S&C=1&O=%7B%22color%22:1,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) ?

I have the longer version and I've verified that they won't fit together, but I'm wondering if the shorter hairpiece can work.

Answer (score 6):

No.

The hairpiece you link appears to be the same mould as the standard non-movie Wonder Woman figure. The hair falls quite close to the back of the minifigure torso, so there's no room for a neck bracket.

[image: picture of wonder woman with neck attachment and wings]

If you're looking to add wings to your Wonder Woman, it might be worth investing in a helmet or hairpiece that doesn't cover the back of the torso.

Comment: thanks, it looked shorter from it's picture on bricklink.